# FromEvent Keyup Filter is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

I am implementing very simple search function in my app using FromEvent KeyUp and debounceTime as following code :

```
<input matInput #inputSearch>

@ViewChild('inputSearch', { static: false }) input: ElementRef;

fromEvent(this.input.nativeElement, 'keyup')
      .pipe(
        filter((val: any) => val.target.value.length > 3),
        debounceTime(500),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        switchMap((val: any) => this.userService.get(val.target.value))
      )
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
      });
```

Its working as soon as i type something in the input box, but as you can see i added a filter and it supposes to only fire the api call when the value of input > 3.

However, the filter is not working. I stuck now on this problem. 
Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: How is the filter not working - is it firing after the length is 2 or 1? Is the method not firing at all? More information is needed.

Comment: I guess that you put the `fromEvent` wrong position. I suggest that use angular reactive form to handle this action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `fromEvent`, `keyup`, instead you can use handy way recommended by Angular. You can use `Angular Forms` and `valueChanges` as below to achieve what you want.

**HTML**

```
<div [formGroup]="myGroup">
  <input formControlName="search" type="text" placeholder="search">
</div>
```

Define your `FormGroup` as below in Component.

```
myGroup: FormGroup;

this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
   search: new FormControl()
});
```

Then you can `subscribe` to value changes of search `FormControl` as below.

```
this.myGroup.get('search').valueChanges.debounceTime(500)
  .subscribe((val: any) => {

    const search = val.trim();
    if (search.length > 3) {
      console.log('Search Term => ', search);
      // TODO: Handle your API Call Here.
    }
});
```

Find a working **[StackBlitz Here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h9ybdr)**